# Create tablespace "error in creating database file, access denied (OS 5)"

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I try to create a database file in this location [image]

I've checked the route and everything, I've tried several times to create the tablespace like this...

[image]

...but as you can see, I was just lead to several errors. What can I do? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have permission on that directory? Under which user are you running SQL*PLUS? Administrator?

Comment: @JSapkota the user you are logged into Oracle as does not matter. It's the Oracle service that needs permission on the directory in order to create the datafile

Answer (score -1):

Do you have permission on this directory?
Under which user are you running SQL*PLUS? Administrator? – 
if no than got permission first

if yes

```
CREATE TABLESPACE lmtbsb DATAFILE 'file_path/lmtbsb01.dbf' SIZE 50M
    EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE;
```

Comment: I'm logged as SYSTEM... When I try to use that order, it leads me to the same error. Thank you very much for your quick answer though!

Comment: you are not added '01'  or any other 'file_path/lmtbsb01.dbf'  in your file_name add it than create

Comment: Do you mean create a something01.dfb file as in your example apart from the one I want to create, or that I should add the "01" next to the name of my file? I'm sorry, I know I am an absolute newbie.

Comment: yes add 01 or any other in file name

Comment: Same error... I don't know what it can be.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error and I fixed it by giving permissions to the Oracle user that I was using, as shown below

[image: fix error]